# I have written Program to convert Hour to Min

Tags: python, string

This Is my Program Code where I have created a function that is converting Hour to Min.

```
    def convertToHM(Mins):
        hours = Mins / 60
        minutes = Mins % 60 
        
        return str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes)
    
Mins = int(input("Enter Minutes: "))
print("OutPut Is " + convertToHM(Mins))
```

OutPut Of the above Code.
Enter Minutes: 63
OutPut Is **1.05:3**

My Question Is why it is giving 1.05:3, I want my output as 1:3 where I am making Mistakes?

I even have tried to convert string to integer

```
return int(str(hours)) + ':' + int(str(minutes))

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
File "<string>", line 10, in convertToHM
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.05'**
```

so it is giving me the above error.

How should I overcome this error? I am a very Beginner in Python Language

Comment: use `//` for hours calculation to have integer value

Comment: convert to `int` before converting to `str`

Comment: Okay But why we need to convert to Str can you please give brief idea

Answer (score 0):

`/` is float division, you need integer division `//`

Also, you can use `str.zfill` to show the zero padded minutes

```py
def convertToHM(Mins):
    hours = Mins // 60
    minutes = Mins % 60
    return str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes).zfill(2)
Mins = int(input("Enter Minutes: "))
print("OutPut Is " + convertToHM(Mins))
```

```py
Enter Minutes: >? 63
OutPut Is 1:03
```

Without `zfill`, output is `1:3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function math.trunc to truncate your number and keep the integer part of it :

```
    hours = math.trunc(Mins / 60)
```